# How could I save users' login state in a nativescript application

Tags: nativescript

Recently I'm programing an app with nativescript, and now I have a problem that I don't know how to save the user's login state. For example, if user login at the first time, he will not need to login in the future. So how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do use `application-settings` on my apps, the same module that the other answers suggest.

You can get code samples for [Angular](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/application-settings) and [vanilla](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/application-settings) JS.

Also, in one of my apps, I've created a `config.ts` class that handles my app's settings:

```
import {
    getBoolean,
    setBoolean,
    getNumber,
    setNumber,
    getString,
    setString,
    hasKey,
    remove,
    clear
} from "application-settings";

export class Config {

    clear() {
        clear()
    }

    get token(): string { 
        return getString('token')
    }

    set token(token: string) {
        setString('token', token)
    }

    get userId(): string {
        return getString('userId')
    }

    set userId(userId: string) {
        setString('userId', userId)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **application-settings** module to store your session key or something, if no value is there consider it's first time login.

Docs: https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/application-settings

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`application-settings`](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_application_settings_) module to store different type of values (e.g. `number`, `string`, `boolean`) and use the module to check if the user has already logged in.